# Want me hanging out or to hang out

Tags: gerunds, verb-usage

What I'd learned so far is that we can only use infinitive after 'want'. 
But today I saw "mom doesn't want me hanging out with you anymore" in an english book..
Is it correct to use -ing form after want?

Also I want to know if these sentences below sound natural to you guys.

- > Mom doesn't want me to keep hanging out with you anymore.
- > Mom doesn't want me to keep in touch with you anymore.
- > Mom doesn't want me to meet you anymore.

Answer (score 1):

According to [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/en/node/1404/) and the Cambridge Dictionary [[1]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/common-verbs/want) and [[2]](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/verb-patterns/verb-patterns-verb-infinitive-or-verb-ing), using a gerund after *want* instead of an infinitive is **incorrect.**

Therefore, using *keep* in the sentences is also incorrect (except in the second sentence, since *keep in touch* is an expression).

All your sentences are perfectly natural, but you'll probably hear English speakers use *us* more often when talking directly to other people:

> Mom doesn't want **us** to hang out anymore.
>
> Mom doesn't want **us** to keep in touch.
>
> Mom doesn't want **us** to meet anymore.

Comment: +1 *want* can also be used with a gerund-participal in concealed passive--e.g. "The soup wants stirring."

Comment: "Mom doesn't want us to hang out anymore." You usually hang out either with someone or at some place. "Mom doesn't want us to hang out" means that she doesn't want us to spend time aimlessly (to waste time). It doesn't mean that she is against our hanging out/keeping in touch/meeting with one another. [The source](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hang+out)